# PHP Named Pipe Problem

Tags: windows, mysql, php, named-pipes

I am trying to test a website on a local machine that has Windows 7 installed. I want to use named pipes to connect to the MySQL server, but `mysql_connect()` seems to throw an error:

```
[2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)
```

For some reason it's still using TCP. I'm testing with a simple PHP (5.3) script:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die();

echo "It works!";

?>
```

The MySQL client works fine. It's just a problem with PHP (note: using TCP instead works).

This is what I have in *my.ini*:

```
[client]

pipe
socket=mysql

[mysqld]

skip-networking
enable-named-pipe
socket=mysql
```

I tried setting these variables in *php.ini*:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket = mysql
mysql.default_socket = mysql
mysqli.default_socket = mysql
```

Comment: Well, I'm used to work with CentOS/RHEL desktop/server, and never get this error before. I know that php and mysql tend to get error on windows 7. Did you try your code on another computer? Xp? linux? Maybe the problem is from your 7.

Comment: @Anarko_Bizounours I've never tried with named pipes. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) it says that specifying the host name as `.` forces the use of named pipes in Windows, but I get "no such host is known". It still seems to be using TCP (trying to connect via tcp://.:3306).

Comment: By all that's holy, don't use bare `mysql_*`. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug affecting the VC9 binaries. See: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48082 (if the link doesn't work, try this [cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:teve-i5CO5YJ:bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48082%20mysql_connect%20pipe&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&source=www.google.co.uk) version). According to *andrey@php.net*:

> A patch is being worked on.
>
> Support will be in the next minor PHP
>   version, be it 5.4 or something else.
>
> 5.3.x won't get this, as this is classified as new feature.

---

As the person that asked this question, I'd like to mention that I was using the Apache web server. The [PHP downloads page for Windows](http://windows.php.net/download/) does say that VC9 binaries should not be used with Apache (I was not aware at the time), but this seems to be a separate issue, since IIS users also had the same problem, if you look at the bug report.

Comment: To clarify something (since you have read just first part of 2-sentenced message): The PHP downloads page for Windows says: _Do NOT use VC9 version with **apache.org** binaries. **VC9 versions of Apache** can be fetched at Apache Lounge. **We use their binaries to build the Apache SAPIs**._

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, when I said VC9 binaries should not be used with Apache, I meant the apache.org binaries, not Apache, sorry. I was just pointing out that this is a separate issue.